# How to obtain cross-validated r-square from linear model in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, cross-validation

I have a linear model in R.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100, x+z)
mydata <- data.frame(x,y,z)

fit <- lm(y ~ x + z, mydata)
```

I would like to obtain an estimate of the out of sample r-square. I was thinking of using some form k-fold cross validation.

- What code in R takes a linear model fit and returns a cross-validated r-square?
- Or is there some other approach to obtaining cross-validated r-square using R?

Comment: May be off-topic.. and good [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why? It is about how to implement a statistical technique in the language [r](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) which has close to 30,000 questions. If you'd prefer, I could remove the statistical elements of the question and just focus on R implementation?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html

Comment: @NPE Many thanks. That looks like it will do the trick. Once I've applied it, I'll post an example of how it applies to the example above.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim: If you search for `DAAG` on this site, you'll find some relevant questions and answers.

Comment: @geektrader I thought about cross-validated, but they generally refer questions about R implementation to Stack Overflow. I agree this question has a mix of both statistics and implementation, but I felt that the emphasis was on R implementation and therefore was more suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @geektrader. Okay. I'ved edited the question to be purely about R implementation.

Answer (score 4):

So what follows is a slight adaptation to [the example that @NPR linked to from statsmethods](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html). Essentially I adapted the example to make it a function.

```
library(bootstrap)

k_fold_rsq <- function(lmfit, ngroup=10) {
    # assumes library(bootstrap)
    # adapted from http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html
    mydata <- lmfit$model
    outcome <- names(lmfit$model)[1]
    predictors <- names(lmfit$model)[-1]

    theta.fit <- function(x,y){lsfit(x,y)}
    theta.predict <- function(fit,x){cbind(1,x)%*%fit$coef} 
    X <- as.matrix(mydata[predictors])
    y <- as.matrix(mydata[outcome]) 

    results <- crossval(X,y,theta.fit,theta.predict,ngroup=ngroup)
    raw_rsq <- cor(y, lmfit$fitted.values)**2 # raw R2 
    cv_rsq <- cor(y,results$cv.fit)**2 # cross-validated R2

    c(raw_rsq=raw_rsq, cv_rsq=cv_rsq)
}
```

So using the data from before

```
# sample data
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100, x+z)
mydata <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

We can fit a linear model and call the cross validation function:

```
# fit and call function
lmfit <- lm(y ~ x + z, mydata)
k_fold_rsq(lmfit, ngroup=30)
```

And get the resulting raw and cross-validated r-square:

```
  raw_rsq    cv_rsq 
0.7237907 0.7050297
```

**Caveat:** While `raw_rsq` is clearly correct and `cv_rsq` is in the ball park that I expect, note that I haven't yet examined exactly what the `crosval` function does. So use at your own risk and if anyone has any feedback, it would be most welcome. It's also only designed for linear models with an intercept and standard main effects notation.

Comment: This function breaks for models with factor predictors. Example: `fit = lm("Sepal.Length ~ Species", data = iris); k_fold_rsq(fit)` `Error in lsfit(x, y) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
In lsfit(x, y) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement this with interactions

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function for doing this. It also works for nominal predictors. It only works for `lm` objects (I think), but could easily be expanded to `glm` etc.

```
# from
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/16030020/3980197
# via http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html

#' Calculate k fold cross validated r2
#'
#' Using k fold cross-validation, estimate the true r2 in a new sample. This is better than using adjusted r2 values.
#' @param lmfit (an lm fit) An lm fit object.
#' @param folds (whole number scalar) The number of folds to use (default 10).
#' @export
#' @examples
#' fit = lm("Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length", data = iris)
#' MOD_k_fold_r2(fit)
MOD_k_fold_r2 = function(lmfit, folds = 10, runs = 100, seed = 1) {
  library(magrittr)

  #get data
  data = lmfit$model

  #seed
  if (!is.na(seed)) set.seed(seed)

  v_runs = sapply(1:runs, FUN = function(run) {
    #Randomly shuffle the data
    data2 = data[sample(nrow(data)), ]

    #Create n equally size folds
    folds_idx <- cut(seq(1, nrow(data2)), breaks = folds, labels = FALSE)

    #Perform n fold cross validation
    sapply(1:folds, function(i) {
      #Segement your data by fold using the which() function

      test_idx = which(folds_idx==i, arr.ind=TRUE)
      test_data = data2[test_idx, ]
      train_data = data2[-test_idx, ]

      #weights
      if ("(weights)" %in% data) {
        wtds = train_data[["(weights)"]]
      } else {
        train_data$.weights = rep(1, nrow(train_data))
      }

      #fit
      fit = lm(formula = lmfit$call$formula, data = train_data, weights = .weights)

      #predict
      preds = predict(fit, newdata = test_data)

      #correlate to get r2
      cor(preds, test_data[[1]], use = "p")^2
    }) %>%
      mean()
  })

  #return
  c("raw_r2" = summary(lmfit)$r.squared, "cv_r2" = mean(v_runs))
}
```

Testing it:

```
fit = lm("Petal.Length ~ Species", data = iris)
MOD_k_fold_r2(fit)
#>    raw_r2     cv_r2 
#> 0.9413717 0.9398156
```

And on the OP sample:

```
> MOD_k_fold_r2(lmfit)
#raw_r2  cv_r2 
# 0.724  0.718
```

Answer (score 0):

Discussion over on stats.stackexchange (e.g., [link 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129937/k-fold-cross-validation-r-squared-value), and [link 2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186396/appropriate-way-to-calculate-cross-validated-r-square)) argues that mean-squared error (MSE) should be used rather than `R^2`.

Leave-one-out cross-validation (special case of k-folds cv where k=N) has a property allowing the quick computation of CV MSE for linear models using a simple formula.  See section 5.1.2 of "Introduction to Statistical Learning in R".  The following code should compute RMSE value for `lm` models (using Equation 5.2 from same section):

```
sqrt(sum((residuals(fit)/(1-hatvalues(fit)))^2)/length(fit$residuals))
```

Which you could compare to the "regular" RMSE:

```
summary(fit)$sigma
```

or RMSE obtained from 5- or 10-fold cross-validation, I suppose.